# Extract information from json

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I have the following object from my controller, which has a name, a list of beans and a list of operations:

```
{
  "name": "Charge",
  "beans": [

  ],
  "operations": [
    {
      "name": "getSize",
      "returnType": "java.lang.Integer",
      "description": "empty description",
      "parameters": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "truncate",
      "returnType": "java.lang.Void",
      "description": "empty description",
      "parameters": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "count",
      "returnType": "java.lang.Integer",
      "description": "empty description",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "javaCode",
          "type": "java.lang.String",
          "value": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "update",
      "returnType": "java.lang.Integer",
      "description": "empty description",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "javaSelectCode",
          "type": "java.lang.String",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "name": "javaUpdateCode",
          "type": "java.lang.String",
          "value": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "delete",
      "returnType": "java.lang.Integer",
      "description": "empty description",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "javaCode",
          "type": "java.lang.String",
          "value": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "dump",
      "returnType": "java.lang.Void",
      "description": "empty description",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "javaSelectCode",
          "type": "java.lang.String",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "name": "destinationPath",
          "type": "java.lang.String",
          "value": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "select",
      "returnType": "java.lang.String",
      "description": "empty description",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "javaCode",
          "type": "java.lang.String",
          "value": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "$$hashKey": "object:620"
}
```

Basically I want to display all the operations from this object in a dropdown menu.

So I was thinking of having something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="operation in object.operations">
  {{operation.name}}
</div>
```

Except the code above doesn't display anything on the screen, no errors in the console, nothing.

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

Javascript service:

```
app.controller('selectAll', ['$http', '$scope' , '$rootScope', function ($http, $scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.response;
    $scope.operations;

    $rootScope.$on("invokeSelectAll", function(){
        $scope.invokeSelectAll();
    });

    $scope.invokeSelectAll  = function(){
        $scope.response = $http.post('/invoke/selectAll/', $rootScope.dataObj);
        $scope.object = JSON.stringify($rootScope.object);
        console.log(" object operation from selectAll " + $scope.object);
        $scope.response.then(function(data) {
            $scope.responses = data.data ? data.data : "Select Operation not supported on this bean";
        });
    }
}]);
```

Screenshot of dev console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eblww.jpg

Comment: try using *ngFor

Comment: This for Angular or AngularJS? I have a feeling you have used the wrong tag

Comment: I'm using angular 1.6

Comment: Everything looks fine for me, sorry, I don't see an issue...

Comment: JSON.parse for response received

Comment: Yes, @Amit should be right, `parse` instead of `stringify`

Comment: $scope.object = JSON.stringify($rootScope.object); so $scope.object is now a string and not an object

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify()` to create a JSON string from a JavaScript object.

Use `JSON.parse()` to parse a JSON string to a JavaScript object.

In your case, you need to use `JSON.parse()` because you get a JSON string from the server and want to parse it to a JavaScript object.

```
$scope.object = JSON.parse($rootScope.object);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using JSON.stringify which is used to change javascript object to string and store it as a string only.

You should  Parse the data with JSON.parse(), and the data becomes a JavaScript object. and you can easily use that in ng-repeat.

Try it ,It will work fine